# how to dynamically show a mat-progress-bar when a button is clicked

Tags: angular, angular-material

Hi I am have about 6000 rows of data I am filtering in my mat-table that takes about 5 seconds to filter when a "Filter" button is clicked. I am trying to show a Mat-Progress-Bar while the function is being called. I have attached a sample stackblitz to try and repro my problem. I want the Mat-Progress-Bar to only show when the "Filter" button is clicked and disappear when the the data is renderded.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4ttand-8ckvs7?file=src/app/table-basic-flex-example.ts

```
<button mat-raised-button (click)="filterTable()"> Filter Table on Weight!</button>

<mat-progress-bar *ngIf="isLoading" color="primary" mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>

export class TableBasicFlexExample {
  isLoading = true

filterTable() {
         this.dataSource = this.dataSource.filter((item) => { 
         return Math.floor(item.weight) > 10});
         this.isLoading = false;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4ttand-i6mwao?file=src/app/table-basic-flex-example.ts

PS: Don't forget to delete setTimeout, I used it to "simulate" the time it takes your function to filter.

```js
filterTable() {
    this.isLoading = true
    this.dataSource = this.dataSource.filter((item) => { 
    console.log(Math.floor(item.weight));
    return Math.floor(item.weight) > 10});
    this.isLoading = false;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include your solution to the asker's question in the answer, and not in an external website. You may, however, keep the external URL so the user can try it.

Comment: Thanks but this still doesn't work with dynamic data on my dataSource filter function.

Comment: I got this to work after tweaking some of my ngOnInit logic

Comment: @MarcSances I edited the answer. My bad, it's my first answer.